# Encoding buffer to base64 is not working

Tags: node.js, base64, aws-lambda

I have a function that takes an image url, resizes the image buffer and returns a base64 image format of it. The frustrating thing is I had this working and cannot see any code change that would impact this function, yet there is something not quite right. When I log the base64, I see what starts to look like a base64 encoding, but it is a lot smaller than it was previously for the same image, and it ends with `%` and not the expected, and previously seen `=`. Here is the fairly straight forward function I have:

```
const bufferRequest = request.defaults({ encoding: null });
const sharp = require('sharp');

function returnBase64(imgUrl, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bufferRequest.get(imgUrl, params, function (err, res, body) {
        let resized = sharp(body).resize(params.width, params.height);
        resized.toFormat('jpeg')
        .toBuffer()
        .then((resultBuffer) => {
          let formattedImage = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(resultBuffer).toString('base64');
          console.log(formattedImage);
          resolve(formattedImage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        })
      });
    })
}
```

Again, this worked fine before, and the worrying thing is, I do not get an error. The code that returns a response still logs this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "body": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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%
```

As you can see, the base64 `=` is missing, and the closing json markup too. Previously the body was much bigger. Is this an iTerm thing or have I done something silly? What does this `%` mean, is it a special character or wild card? I am literally mind blocked.

**Update**

I have noticed the above issue is only present when I test using the `lambda-local` library to test with command `lambda-local  -f ~/Desktop/project/handler.js -e ~/Desktop/lambdaTesting/testEvent.json`. The `console.log(formattedImage)` is as shown above.

But when I run my test suite that uses mocha by running `npm test`, the full base64 is present, ending in the expected `=`. This to me narrows it down to 1 of 2 things:

1: There is an issue with lambda-local waiting for the full response that I am unaware of.

2: There is an async issue handled by mocha.done() that is not being handled by lambda-local.

Comment: Can you call `toString('base64')` directly on `resultBuffer`? Any improvements that way?

Comment: @cassini I tried that and no change. I really am starting to think that the `%` is cutting off the rest of the data in the console. Is that an idiotic suggestion?

Comment: There is no such limitation in the console. What will the log look like if you are logging only the `formattedImage` variable, before resolving the promise? And from where is your logged content coming, a response that is sent back?

Comment: The logged content above is a response I create to send back to requests for resized images. When I log the `formattedImage` before the resolve, predictably, I get the contents of the body shown in the original post.

Comment: Those kind of logs occur when the network communication is not done yet, so we don't have the whole content at logging moment. As you are logging it on the backend and not on the client, it is really strange.

Comment: True, hence the node tag. That and the use of the request module which retruns the response/body on completion. If I were using native https.request, I would have to have an `on('data')` and `on('end')` to make sure I was handling the data correctly. Not an issue here

Comment: This seems to be a lambda-local dependency issue, rather than a code issue. I'll keep this open until I find a fix unless it is recommended I close.

Comment: The missing `=` is not an issue as it just represents padding.